# Загрузка файлов на Google Drive по URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, есть ли возможность грузить файлы на Google Drive прямо по URL?
К примеру есть файл `http://site.ru/catalog/file.xxx`

Возможно ли загрузить его сразу на Google Drive?

Из локальной понятно как, но вот как отправить ему URL и чтобы он скачал файл сразу на диск непонятно.

Comment: Есть библиотека https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2. Можете ее попробовать

Comment: Увидел только Download file’s content from download_url.
Про загрузку на диск не нашёл:(